# how can i add more than one custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I want to add more than one taxonomy.
i tried `get_terms( 'CUSTOM_TAXONOMY','CUSTOM_TAXONOMY-2', array`
but second tax not work

```
    $i                 = 1;
// get the terms you need
$terms        = get_terms( 'CUSTOM_TAXONOMY', array('orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'DESC', 'hide_empty' => 0 ) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed

```
 $terms = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => array('bank','dovlet_qurumu'),
    'hide_empty' => false,
]); her
```